# Why does exec'ing a wine program produce ansi escape sequences in stdout?

Tags: c++, linux, mingw-w64, wine

I've built a win32 executable with MinGW. Running it from the console correctly invokes Wine, and outputs normal text.

However, if I load that executable programmatically with "exec" functions, every character output by the child-process is prefaced by an ansi escape sequence (S becomes `[?25lS`). I think this means that the forwarded stdout is double escaped?

Is this a function of wine? Is this something I can disable? Is this a feature of the windows libraries I'm linking to? Does MinGW cause this?

I've tried changing the locale `cout.imbue( locale("C") )`, using printf instead of cout, calling `system("chcp 1252");` in the child-process, and a few other miscellaneous tricks. Nothing seems to fix the output from the child-process.

Comment: Running a program (any program) from the console causes your shell to invoke `exec` in exactly the same way your own program would. Perhaps you can post a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an issue with the console in older versions of Eclipse, rather than a general/programming issue. The solution for developing and debugging is to upgrade Eclipse or use a different IDE.

Oops!